# How to pass external application.yaml file to docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, spring-boot-admin

This is my docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine AS base

WORKDIR /app

FROM base as builder
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew build

FROM base

RUN adduser -D -g dgm dgm
RUN chown dgm:dgm /app
USER dgm
COPY --from=builder --chown=dgm:dgm /app/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=dgm:dgm /app/build/libs/application.yaml ./config/application.yaml
#COPY --from=builder --chown=dgm:dgm /app/build/libs/application.yaml .
#RUN chmod 777 config/* && chmod 777 config
# Run the jar file
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
CMD ["--spring.config.location=config/application.yaml"]

VOLUME [ "/app/config" ]
```

How to run this docker image with external application.yaml file.

I tried few ways.

```
docker run -it demo --entrypoint "/home/durgpal/application.yaml"
dokcer run it demo /home/durgpal/application.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using a volume?

`docker run -v /home/durgpal/application.yaml:/app/config/application.yaml demo`